# MongoDB Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

I managed to run MongoDB on Codeigniter using Alex Bilbie` library. The operations go well (connection, queries etc. ) but sometimes I get these PHP notices:

```
Message: Mongo::__construct() [mongo.--construct]: localhost:27017: pool get (0x4bfab20)

Filename: libraries/Mongo_db.php

Line Number: 1274
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Mongo::__construct() [mongo.--construct]: localhost:27017: found in pool (0x4bfab20)

Filename: libraries/Mongo_db.php
```

Is there a way to get rid of these? or maybe hide them..as they don't seem to mess up my pages in another way than splashing into the user's screen.

EDIT

On a few pages though, I use the JQgrid and when the errors show up they mess up my HTTP response and render some messy data.

Comment: You currently have `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL`, if you do `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` you will see all errors except notices.

Comment: I'm note sure hiding them is the solution. I need to see other notices too..

Comment: @Gavin radashk is correct, ideally the answers below are all wrong. These errors should not even show and they don't for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific notice messages here have been removed in the MongoDB PHP driver 1.2.11 or later (see [PHP-431](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-431)).  Upgrading your MongoDB driver to the latest should remove the excessive notice logging.

General notes on proper settings for Code Igniter logging in production still apply...

The `E_NOTICE` level of error reporting is intended to warn you about possible bugs or typos.  It is typically only used as a development setting rather than for production messages.

The default [error_reporting setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) in PHP4 and PHP5 is actually set to ignore these:

```
E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

The Code Igniter `index.php` has an *application environment* setting which normally shows all errors for `development` and suppresses error reporting for `testing` and `production`.  You should set this appropriately:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

If you actually want to capture these messages for a production environment you should update the `production` settings in your index.php so that instead of `error_reporting(0)` you have:

- [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)() set to appropriate level of detail
- [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) `off`
- [log_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log_errors) `on`
- [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) path set

For example, in `index.php` you could have:

```
case 'production':
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','Off');
    ini_set('log_errors','On');
    ini_set('error_log','/var/log/php5.log');
break;
```

That way the messages/notices will still be saved to the `error_log` if you want to review them, but they will not be shown to the end user.

Comment: I actually saw these exact errors before on here not that long ago. This is not the first time "pool" errors have shown up. Thing is I am not sure if anyone knows what these are, I have searched the constructor of the PHP driver (which is where the last person was getting them) but couldn't track down where these were coming from. I wouldn't mind knowing myself what it means by those very obscure messages, are these debug messages by any chance?

Comment: @Sammaye: these specific messages are "notice" level errors, and most have been removed as of the MongoDB PHP 1.2.11 driver (see [PHP-431](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-431)).  I think the general advice on Code Igniter still applies; you wouldn't normally want to see these on production or display to end users.

Comment: So upgrading his driver should stop these messages? Because you still don't want your log full of E_NOTICES that you dont wanna see. So I would say upgrading the driver would be the best answer here right?

Comment: @Sammaye: upgrading *and* setting appropriate logging. These aren't the only `notice` messages that will get displayed to an end user (*that* problem is not specific to MongoDB extension).  I updated my answer to include the driver upgrade, though :).

Comment: I've reinstalled everything and things seem fine for the moment.I'll post my feedback tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, there are a few things you could do. This is not an answer regarding a fix to the MongoDB error you are receveing, but rather regarding some methods in which you could hide the errors.

a) Use the '@' operator to ignore any error outputs from the method being called in which outputs the errors you are receiving. This would result in you renaming the method call to the following `@method_outputting_mongodb_error($foo,$bar);`.

b) Turn off error reporting in CodeIgniter. This is not the best method as all other errors will not be outputted.

There is a good link here re: how you can turn off error reporting: http://phpdog.blogspot.fr/2012/02/codeigniter-error-reporting-handling.html

Answer (score -1):

As @Stennie mentions this has been fixed in later versions of the driver: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-431

Try and upgrade.

Also this only existed on the Windows driver and only start happening after v1.2.1. I know that because the guy who made that JIRA also tried 1.2.1 on my advice and he didn't get those `E_NOTICE`s. I remember having the conversation that actually triggered that JIRA now :).

Unlike others I don't think you should "hide" these errors with `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`. No one is quite decided on hiding E_NOTICE however the general concensus is that it is not the best thing. Of course you would not want your logs to be filled with all this debug info about the MongoDB extension, instead the MongoDB extension should be silent (as you think it should).

Another reason I would not hide E_NOTICE is because of the php.ini of later versions of PHP:

```
; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

By default PHP will actually install for Production Value (as it does for me) as such the default for PHP error reporting is:

```
E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

This is the value I have for error_reporting on both my AWS and my local Ubuntu server 12.04 and I have not changed the values since installing as such the default value I gain from installing PHP from both repo and source is:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

So the recommended default setup for production for later PHP versions (and probably future ones) actually shows `E_NOTICE`, which is useful but not if the logs are being filled with stuff from the Mongo extension.

Edit: Downvoter care to explain? I have basically given the same answer as @Stennie, why the downvote?

I have edited my answer to actually take the conversation in the comments on this answer and @Stennie's answer into consideration so the answer makes more sense now.

Comment: Actually the messages are related to logging levels, not O/S version.  As mentioned in my answer, the PHP default is to suppress `E_NOTICE` messages .. but some development environments (Code Igniter, in this case) enable `E_ALL` by default.  Upgrading the MongoDB driver should remove the excessive notices, but doesn't fix the general application misconfiguration of displaying all messages to the end user.  Code Igniter has *application environment* settings which should be used.

Comment: @Stennie PHP 5.3+ has E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED by default as the logging level. I remember this on Google groups. Tested with the Linux version didn't get the logs but with the Windows one I did. That is why Marcin Gil said that it was thought it had been compiled with debug since it was shwing the same behaviour as the flag said in the PHP Doc and the Linux driver was not. So I thought it had been compiled weirdly so he did.

Comment: @Stennie Yea I see why you say that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting the doc is out of date. If you download the latest PHP 5.3 or 5.4 you will find in the php.ini default is now to show all and hide deprecated notices. You got caught by the same hook as me :)

Comment: @Stennie I have added the php.ini notice to me question

Comment: So isn't this now the same, then, as my answer? ;-).  Less the specifics on Code Igniter which the OP is actually using ...

Comment: @Stennie kind of except it seems it is recommended not to turn off E_NOTICE now. So infact despite using CI he would still see this logging on the recommend production setup as such simply hiding it probably isn't the best answer :)

Comment: @Stennie Though reading your first comment again (properly) I agree with the general app misconfiguration of showing errors to the client.

Comment: @radashk Ah, Weird your dir syntax is same as Linux unless thats how CI errors show :) I have never used CI so I wouldn't know.